# Unknown notation used in matrix proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, problem-solving

I have been given the following task (by my professor, with no mentionable context):

Prove that $\displaystyle
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$ $\displaystyle
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} \\
\end{array}
\right]
= \left[ b_{11}A_1+b_{21}A_2 : b_{12}A_1+b_{22}A_2 \right]$, where $\displaystyle A_1 =
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
a_{11} \\
a_{21} \\
\end{array}
\right]$ and $\displaystyle A_2=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
a_{12} \\
a_{22} \\
\end{array}
\right]$. Generalise the result to $n \times n$ matrices.

---

However, I don't know what is implied by the notation:

> $\left[ b_{11}A_1+b_{21}A_2 : b_{12}A_1+b_{22}A_2 \right]$

So, I can't reasonably hope to satisfy the desired results, when I am uncertain what exactly is desired.

What is implied by this?

Comment: Do you mean first column @uniquesolution ?

Comment: @Tucker, yes, of course, thank you.

Comment: Alex what is implied by this is that each column of the resultant matrix is a linear combination of the columns of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly means that what's on the left of ":" is the first column of the matrix that results from the product, and what's on the right is the second column.

Comment: So, where $c_n$ is the $n^{th}$ column of a given matrix, $[c_1:c_2:c_3:...:c_n] = [c_1|c_2|c_3|...|c_n]$?